# Does [css-positioning] deserve to stand alone? +Cleanup

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Currently, [css-positioning](/questions/tagged/css-positioning) is synonymized into [css](/questions/tagged/css). However, there are currently several other positioning tags in existence that seem to indicate that CSS positioning is a wide enough issue that it **does** deserve its own, separate tag.

- [absolute-positioning](/questions/tagged/absolute-positioning) **× 512**
- [position-fixed](/questions/tagged/position-fixed) **× 173**
- [relative-positioning](/questions/tagged/relative-positioning) **× 118**

The `position` property being a **single** property, all of these should be synonymized into a single CSS positioning tag.

There are also these other tags that probably shouldn't be synonymized but need to be taken care of:

- [position](/questions/tagged/position) **× 1478**
  Honestly, I think this one should be burninated. It is extremely vague and used as a meta-tag in almost anything not related to CSS.
- [positioning](/questions/tagged/positioning) **× 1076**
  This one is more closely related to CSS via its tag wiki, but still mentions its other users and I fear it has a lot of meta-taggings as well. If this one does get combined, it should probably be destroyed first, and then synonymized, to get rid of any non-relevant questions that might be tagged there.
- [divpositioning](/questions/tagged/divpositioning) **× 15**
  Merge and delete the tag.
- [bottom-position](/questions/tagged/bottom-position) **× 8**
  I *believe* it's referring to the `bottom` property in CSS. If that's true, merge and delete the tag.

---

Also, you should get rid of that [css-postioning](/questions/tagged/css-postioning) synonym. I don't know why a misspelled synonym was ever added in the first place...

Comment: +1 since CSS positioning is all voodoo to me.. It's sort of harder and more extensivly used/abused than the rest of the CSS properties..

Comment: For even more CSS tag weirdness: http://stackoverflow.com/users/405015/thirtydot?tab=tags&sort=votes&page=1

Comment: I'll look at this later - I'm going to bed.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Is it later yet, or do you slumber for extended periods of time?

Comment: ***I PROMISE I WILL WORK ON THIS SOON***

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: No rush, it's only been a year you know, and the number of positioning questions has only like doubled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is, for the most part, completed. What's been done:

[css-position](/questions/tagged/css-position) has been created to handle all questions relating to the `position` property, as well as its cousins `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left`. It has the following synonyms attached to it:

- [css-positioning](/questions/tagged/css-positioning)
- [absolute-positioning](/questions/tagged/absolute-positioning)
- [relative-positioning](/questions/tagged/relative-positioning)
- [position-fixed](/questions/tagged/position-fixed)

---

[divpositioning](/questions/tagged/divpositioning) and [bottom-position](/questions/tagged/bottom-position) have been destroyed.

---

I'm currently in the process of [retagging the non-CSS questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/positioning+-div+-twitter-bootstrap+-jquery+-css+-css3+-css-float+-css-selectors+-css-positioning+-css-transitions+-css-sprites+-css-animations+-css-transforms+-css3pie+-css-gradient+-css-frameworks+-css-hack+-css-reset+-css-keyframes+-css-menu+-css-overflow+-css-tables+-cssresource+-css-parsing+-javascript+-html+-google-chrome+-firefox) out of the [positioning](/questions/tagged/positioning) tag so those questions can be merged into the new tag.

Then, I will figure out what on Earth to do with the [position](/questions/tagged/position) tag.