# Reverse the [css-selectors] tag being made a synonym for the [css] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

Just a few hours ago the [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) was made a synonym for [css](/questions/tagged/css). I am requesting a ***reversal*** of that for the following reasons:

1. There were **2563** questions tagged with that, far more than any other of the css synonyms (68 is the next highest).
2. Element ***selection*** in css, while of course related to css, is a distinctly different topic than actual ***manipulation*** of the selected element through the properties being applied.

Having a distinction in tags to locate answers and to ask questions related to selection versus manipulation was beneficial for me (and I would guess others).

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: While nothing was stated here as far as discussion goes, it appears that it was reversed within the last 15 minutes or so by someone.

Comment: It was probably BoltClock. He also left [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130669/does-css-positioning-deserve-to-stand-alone-cleanup?noredirect=1#comment567682_130669) on a similar question of mine.

Comment: He is also [the undisputed king of the css-selectors tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/css-selectors/topusers), so you may be right.

Comment: Looks like someone else went and proposed the synonym again a month after this was posted, which was then just approved today. Deleted again.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: That may be an ongoing issue (I don't suppose there is any way to block a synonym suggestion permanently).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wow, I did *not* see this at all. Maybe it's because I was too busy writing up a diatribe of my own, before deciding to hell with the synonym (and filing away what I'd written into Evernote instead).

Thank *you* for bringing this up. I think it's safe to say you were in a far better position to do so than I was, and indeed, you put this much more elegantly and succinctly than I could have.

Comment: Does that mean you are the one who reversed it?

Comment: @ScottS: Yes, indeed.

Comment: At the expense of a frivolous comment---Yeaahhhh!!!!

Comment: @ScottS: Actually, I'd typed YESSSSSSSSSSSSSS in the answer field, but I got too lazy to hold the S key until it reached the character limit so I figured I'd type something more coherent instead to go with your question.

Comment: [I did not initially realize what had happened](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185352/did-something-just-change-to-cause-issues-with-css-selectors-tag/185353#185353), but once I was more informed, I was quick to try to get it reversed.