# Spelling clean-up: "jquerry" and "querry"

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, spelling, clean-up

There are over [300 "querry"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22querry%22) (aka query) and over [100 "jquerry"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22jquerry%22) (aka jquery) typos that need to be corrected.

I have started to go through the questions and answers but it would be great if some other helpful editors could help to correct these 400+ spelling mistakes.

<sup>Don't even get me started on *[pls](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22pls%22)* and *[plz](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22plz%22)* typos. Or even [*u r*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22+u+r+%22) or [*ur*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22%20ur%20%22) (there are awful spelling issues)</sup>

Update, the following have been completed:

- <strike>[queery](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22queery%22)</strike>
- <strike>[jqueery](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22jqueery%22)</strike>

Edit 7/12: completed

- <strike>[jquerry](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22jquerry%22)</strike>

Comment: Could someone plz write some jquerry to automate this?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Even better an autocorrect, when these were added in questions/answers.  I don't like text speak.

Comment: You have stumbled across a truly horrible nest of questions. Many of these are...impressive.

Comment: Cool, the new(ish) search doesn't cap results at 5000.  Also, it looks like "PLS" is actually a thing.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I found that out when I started editing to remove _pls_ a mass replace would not work for that word because of PLS.

Comment: Also [queery](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22queery%22) and [jqueery](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22jqueery%22).

Comment: I see you're trying to enlist the help of the community to correct the spelling of jQuery. You should totally drop that and try jQuerry.

Comment: jQueery is an odd little language

Comment: @BoltClock Why not just make them synonyms?

Comment: correct all the qquueerryy!!

Comment: [Search results don't cap at 10,000 either.](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thx%22)  :(

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn that was a little evil, but I totally laughed out loud in the office.

Comment: @BilltheLizard That is another one that drives me nuts! K THX BYE!

Comment: @BilltheLizard, Wait what? [how is this acceptable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342579/http-status-code-for-update-and-delete)

Comment: @BilltheLizard How about [coz](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22+coz+%22) instead of _because_?  Or [shud](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22+shud+%22) instead of should?

Comment: "coz" is almost as annoying as ["greetz"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22greetz%22).

Comment: @Undo: Because [no](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185358/reverse-the-css-selectors-tag-being-made-a-synonym-for-the-css-tag).

Comment: [meta-tag:status-completed]?

Comment: @ColeJohnson Why? It is not completed.

Comment: Whoops. Saw the update mentioning that some of the tags are an thought all were.

Comment: How would you go about fixing those [if they were part of a quoted passage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752922/mysql-stored-procedure-is-slower-20-times-than-standard-query/16949603#16949603)?

Comment: Re your autocorrect option @bluefeet: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145920/is-it-time-to-do-something-about-spelling-and-grammar

Answer (score 8):

This seriously needs to be automated. I know that there are ways to get out of these things, but these should be removed on post. [:)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22:%29%22) has 190,000 results. Are you kidding me?

I'll put together a list of things that should be cleaned.

- [:)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22:%29%22) - 194,431
- [:-)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22:-%29%22) - 39,636
- [;)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22;%29%22) - 38,482
- [wanna](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22wanna%22) - 18,141
- [;-)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22;-%29%22) - 16,210
- [thx](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thx%22) - 11,892
- [gonna](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22gonna%22) - 11,315
- [pls](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22pls%22) - 9,521
- [plz](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22plz%22) - 8,850
- [ur](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22ur%22) - 7,835
- [:/](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22:/%22) - 7,191
- [coz](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22%20coz%20%22) - 2,170
- [:-/](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22:-/%22) - 1,626
- [wat](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22wat%22) - 1,334
- [u r](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22u%20r%22) - 1,047
- [shud](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22shud%22) - 443
- [wud](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22wud%22) - 195

These numbers are a little too high, especially the smileys. Those definitely need to be banned. That would be a nice feature request.

If I was a talented enough programmer, I would figure out how to build a bot, but I'm not sure even where to start. So one of you programming geniuses out there should build one!

Comment: Well at least plz don't u ban smileys in comments :/ coz we need them thx :)

Comment: My "favorites": [wanna](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22wanna%22) (18,148 results), [gonna](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22gonna%22) (11,318 results)

Comment: I'm so glad that after two years [nothing has changed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/83144/150097) (SO's search engine used to cap results to 5000)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think we can autofix some of these. As Bill pointed out PLS is an actual thing.  Also the `ur` could be an alias used in sql.

Comment: @Bluefeet the smiled can go away though

Comment: An algorithm to find these txtspeak abbreviations will produce a few false positives, but maybe it is better to make 5000 automated edits followed by, say, 200 manual rollbacks instead of 4800 manual edits?

Comment: @Monolo What do you mean?

Comment: @Monolo The problem is that you don't know which 200 posts you have to roll back manually unless you go through all the 5000.

Comment: @Juhana, no I agree - I was thinking that the normal community editing process could take care of it, so maybe "rollback" was a wrong choice of word. Still, having a few hundred problematic posts seems less of a problem than having several thousand. I know that this is controversial, though.

Comment: [Feature Request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185496/we-have-a-community-textspeak-spelling-problem) for emoticons.

Comment: Stack Overflow posts should be written in English. Many posts from the "shud" and "wud" searches simple aren't. Uhg. Time to deploy edits and downvotes until fatigue and despair overcome me.

Comment: [ahhhh](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22plz%22+%22thx%22+%22%3A%29%22+is%3Aquestion)

Comment: @Doorknob Fixed :)

Answer (score 3):

While I'm all for cleaning up the site...

Please for the love of all that's good and right about SO don't just go on a campaign of one word spelling corrections.

Chances are very high that the same user who miss spelled jQuery or put an emoticon in their title has several more issues with there post that need to be corrected.

Comment: When I am editing the questions/answers I clean up as much junk that I see, including voting to close.

Comment: @bluefeet No offense intended. Just a signpost for newer users who may see this post and go on an editing spree.

Comment: Attempting to just make a spelling correction results in the "Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?" message.