# What to do about mass edits of old questions

Tags: discussion, edits

There's a user on SO ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/199048/chris?tab=activity&sort=all), if you must know) doing heaps of edits to old questions, just to remove one tag from them which he feels does not belong. How can we tell him that

1. It's never a good idea to edit so many old questions in such a short time, because they all end up on the home page;
2. If you must delete the tag [webmethods](/questions/tagged/webmethods) because it's the wrong tag, at least put in the right tag [webmethod](/questions/tagged/webmethod) also.

Comment: Did you @-contact the editor?

Comment: Good idea. I just did.

Comment: Also, revert any invalid edits you spot.

Comment: It would help if we had a [limit on suggested edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194114/should-the-amount-of-possible-edit-suggestions-per-day-be-limited), just like we have a limit on edit reviews.

Comment: @DanielDaranas Reverting doesn't help the problem that they were edited and end up on the homepage as new. Besides, the edits are not invalid, just too minor.

Comment: @MrLister Then maybe this is not so much a problem. I've done massive edits of typos in titles ("inheritence", "continous", "lenght") and I think that has been good. The concept of a "too minor" edit does not exist for edits which are not suggested.

Comment: @DanielDaranas Well, yes it does. They can't be rejected as such. But if you don't want to take the time to fully address the issues in a post, just don't bother at all.

Comment: I don't mind editing of minor typos as such, but I do if they're in 4 year old questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just leave a comment. Editors can be @replied, even when their name does not pop up.

Just leave a constructive comment thanking them for their effort, because their willingness to help is always appreciated. And then explain how they might better perform their edits.

They could spread them out a bit more. There is after all no hurry. And of course they should take the whole post into account, fixing all issues. Doing so will slow you down immediately, because you spend more time fixing each individual post. And seeing a - by now - good post pop up, is not nearly as annoying as seeing something old being bumped with all kinds of issues.

And keep in mind that if these are suggested edits getting accepted, then any "problem" is in a large part due to the reviewers. They could have easily sent a message by rejecting such edits as too minor. If all your edits get accepted, why would you need to change your behaviour? You're doing something right, right?

So just leave a gentle comment. That will usually do the trick.

Comment: OK, good points all. It had slipped my mind that you could @ an editor.