# Is it time to recalibrate the pending suggested edit limit?

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, rate-limiting

I've recently decided to start <s>rep farming</s> <s>trying to earn the archaeologist badge</s> cleaning up posts in Ask Ubuntu where I am a low-repper.

Because each of my suggested edits require multi-user approval and final approval *takes too long*, I can only submit one or two edits per day.

I am not a "problematic edit suggestor" (of my first 60+ suggested edits, only a couple have been rejected -- coincidentally my first two edits). I would like the rate limit algorithm to be recalibrated/improved so that users who are consistently making good/thorough/approved edits can be empowered to make more contributions.

Please make any conditional increase related to **edit suggestion outcomes** instead of **rep-based**.  Even 10 or 15 would allow me to contribute more.

Related content:

- [Rate limit suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210416/352329)
- [Should the amount of possible edit suggestions per day be limited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194114/352329)
- [Limit the number of pending suggested edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312942/2943403)
- [Can we increase the capacity of our Suggested Edits queue?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19602/955434)

Edit: I'm returning to this question again because I find myself, again, hamstrung waiting for edit approvals.  I am working a Review Queue and cannot finish my review because I have maxed out my allowance of pending suggested reviews (5).  I think I should have at least enough to edit my allowance of daily Review Queue items -- otherwise, I cannot review effectively.  My stance remains: an increase in allowance would be better for the community that I am volunteering on.

Comment: Perhaps focus your energy on contributing quality questions and answers. As soon as you reach 2K reputation your rate limit is gone :)

Comment: I don't have any questions to ask on Ask Ubuntu and I understand too little about Ubuntu to answer any questions.  Your comment indicates that having the freedom to edit is too tightly bound to reputation.

Comment: No it is bound to reputation for a reason. We want people that are familiar with the subject to make, sometimes quiet substantial, edits that elevate a post. More often then not that requires understanding the subject. Dotting i's and croasing t's is often not substantial enough to merit an edit, especially not one that needs to be reviewed by 3 or more users with sufficient reputation. Anyways the core solution to your problem is to empty the queue faster, not filling it with more posts like you propose.

Comment: @Luuklag with all due respect, reputation has little to do with being familiar with curation or with being a subject matter expert, frankly - I am pretty sure you know that. Agreed, however, that increasing the queue size is not the solution - it bears the same fallacy that adding another lane to a road solves the problem of traffic jams.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My two cents: it's a nice idea but I think you overestimate how much more you would be able to contribute to that specific site. The Suggested Edits queue on Ask Ubuntu is rather large and I've seen it being full from time to time. Giving you (and other prolific editors) more slots, even while simultaneously increasing the queue size to, say 100 instead of 40, will only increase the time to get them approved. You would hit the new limit again soon, and keep on hitting it just as often as you do now. So essentially it would be a one-shot effect and no permanent improvement to the situation.

Would other sites, with more Suggested Edits reviewers, benefit from this feature? Those sites tend (IMHO) to have more editors (with privileges) and have less need of users suggesting edits.

(On a related note: I've always found it weird that beta sites have a limit of 20 pending suggested edits per user, since those tend to have even less reviewers. That might be a remnant of the period where betas were short and most did have a couple of very active moderating users.)

Answer (score 8):

The question is missing a reference to the most recent staff answer on this issue, see [Was the size of the suggested edits queue reduced from 500?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/406075).

I've given the issue some attention since then (March 2020) and on Stack Overflow the *suggested edits* review queue steadily has more than 2000 reviews/day. I consider the number frankly admirable, that's a lot of daily voluntary reviewing. You can compare it with the *close votes* which has between 500-800 daily reviews/day for the same period.

I've said it before, I prefer reviewing suggested edits but close votes are just more impactful in the site's daily curation.

Increasing the size of the queue will arguably not bring more reviews, so even if you doubled the current queue size from 500 to 1000 you'd exhaust that increased capacity in less than a day with the number of reviews tending to remain constant.

---

> make any conditional increase related to edit suggestion outcomes

This won't work because you have plenty of reviewers who reject valid suggested edits for whatever reason. If you check the comments below your question you'll see the usual argument that fixing typos and grammar isn't enough reason to suggest an edit, although the top-voted meta threads say it is.

Comment: There's a long, strong, pro-editing tradition on Ask Ubuntu and I *think* we are pretty good at approving good suggestions (although the OP of this question had a couple of totally unjustified rejections, the main reason given was that the post was old (which is obviously an unacceptable reason to reject)). I am often surprised by rejections I get when I suggest edits on other sites.