# Is there a maximum time limit to approve a suggested edit?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

Usually, my suggestions are approved within 48 hours, but I have a suggested edit that is pending now for several days. In this case, I don't see any chance that it will be either approved or rejected anytime. See the [specific case below](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32060274):

> suggested - Spring Open Projection - Object and Additional Value - Jun 15 at 11:23

Is there a maximum time limit for the submitted suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, suggested edits don't expire. [One of my edits](https://craftcms.meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/19) is already pending since 2018. (It's a very low priority edit, so there's no hurry.)

You can check [the list of queues](https://stackoverflow.com/review/) to see the number of items in the queue; as I'm writing this, it's 485 on Stack Overflow, which is close to the [maximum of 500](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/406075/4751173). Because the reviewers have to spread their efforts across so many review tasks, it takes quite long to have them reviewed. Increasing that limit won't really help, as I've tried to outline [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372084/295232).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. Does this mean that there has not been an empty queue for 4 years?

Comment: @Adrian the four years old pending edit is on a small site with very few high rep users, compared to the big sites. And yeah, on that site the suggested edits queue isn't empty for at least four years. :)